# Please help me clean up my function

Tags: python

Here is my function's objective:

> Define a procedure, `find_last`, that takes as input two strings, a
>   search string and a target string,and returns the last position in the
>   search string where the target string appears, or `-1` if there are no
>   occurrences.

[Here is a link to the question.](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs101/l-48713769/e-48634826/m-48739128)

And here's my function so far:

```
def find_last(target, search):
    find = target.find(search, 0)

    if find != -1:
        targets = target.find(search, find)

        while targets != -1:
            find = find + 1
            targets = target.find(search, find)
        return find - 1
    else:
        return -1
```

The code returns the answer I'm looking for with `return find - 1`, but I know there is a better way to go about doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are coming to SO for homework review?!?!

Comment: @donfede: Nothing wrong with asking how to improve perfectly working code.

Comment: It may be a good candidate for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Answer (score 9):

You basically implemented `target.rfind(search)`.

Answer (score 6):

Why dont you use [`rfind`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html) ?

```
>>> d = "ball foo ball"
>>> f = "ball"
>>> d.rfind(f)
12
```

So your method becomes a 1 liner :)

```
def find_last(target, search):
    return target.rfind(search)
```

You can return `target.rfind(search)` and in the calling method check for `-1` and handle appropriately.

Can't resist to quote this awesome piece from [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/353/)

[image: look I am flying with Python :P]